# HTML Parser fetch link text

Tags: java, html, parsing, hyperlink

I'm using [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) to fetch links from a web page. I need to store the URL, link text and the URL to the parent page containing the link. I have managed to get the link URL as well as the parent URL.

I still ned to get the link text.

```
<a href="url">link text</a>
```

Unfortunately I'm having a hard time figuring it out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static List<LinkContainer> findUrls(String resource) {
    String[] tagNames = {"A", "AREA"};
    List<LinkContainer> urls = new ArrayList<LinkContainer>();
    Tag tag;
    String url;
    String sourceUrl;

    try {

        for (String tagName : tagNames) {

            Parser parser = new Parser(resource);
            NodeList nodes = parser.parse(new TagNameFilter(tagName));

            NodeIterator i = nodes.elements();

            while (i.hasMoreNodes()) {
                tag = (Tag) i.nextNode();
                url = tag.getAttribute("href");
                sourceUrl = tag.getPage().getUrl();

                if (RegexUtil.verifyUrl(url)) {
                    urls.add(new LinkContainer(url, null, sourceUrl));
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (ParserException pe) {
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }

    return urls;
}
```

Comment: if `.getAttribute()` works, I presume `.innerHTML` or `.innerText` would work... or `.nodeValue`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ((LinkTag) tag).getLinkText() ? Personally I prefer n html parser which produces XML according to a well used standard, e.g., xerces or similar. This is what you get from using e.g., http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check the children of each A `Tag`. If you assume that your A tags only have a single child (the text itself), you can use the [getFirstChild()](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Node.html#getFirstChild%28%29) method. This *should* be an instance of [TextNode](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/nodes/TextNode.html), and you can call [getText()](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Node.html#getText%28%29) on this to get the link text.